# How can I check if category is a parent category

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I possibly do this? Also how can I show its subcategories?

Comment: do you mean from a categories table where there is a parent_id set?

Comment: codex.wordpress.org will become your best friend. Check out http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-imake-a-conditional-syays-if-parent-category-is

Comment: something like that. I just don;t know the wordpress's categorization process.. Thanks

Comment: the OP wants to know how to check a category and see if it is a parent NOT get the parent category of a category -- another way to say is "does this category have any children categories" WITHOUT making a query to get the children of the category but to simply return true/false is it HAS children... perhaps the only process available is to query the category for children

Answer (score 7):

Check this

```
<?php $this_category = get_category($cat); ?>
<!-- If category is parent, list it -->
<?php if ($this_category->category_parent == 0) { ?>

<?php } else { ?>
<!-- If category is not parent, list parent category -->
<?php $parent_category = get_category($this_category->category_parent); ?>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I need to check the parent category not the post

but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Updated my answer plz check howz this

Comment: Worked perfectly to only show posts on sub-cat pages. Thanks.